Sprinkler Manifold Connector
I have a leak coming through the sprinkler manifold coupler that’s connected to the water supply. I tried replacing the coupler but I’m not able to detach the coupler from the manifold after unscrewing it from the water line. Is there anyway to repair the coupler or would i need to replace the manifold? 

give us some orientation, what is what

If the gray part on the left is the manifold, with the coupler being the unscrewed fitting in the middle and the waterline on the right, what the picture shows is a monolithic plastic part (the coupling is molded as part of the manifold, it's not parts glued together) so yes, you probably have to replace the manifold to replace the integral coupling.

Thank you! Are the manifold parts typically standard between manufacturers? or do i need to replace with the original part?

No idea. I tend to build such things from standard plumbing parts rather than buy specialty solutions, given a choice. I doubt they are standardized, but I really don't know.
